# removing the dots and colons in the time field

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have the following contents from data.log file. I wish to extract the time value and part of the payload (after deadbeef in the payload, third row, starting second to last byte. Please refer to expected output).

**data.log**

```
print 1: file offset 0x0
ts=0x584819041ff529e0 2016-12-07 14:13:24.124834649 UTC
type: ERF Ethernet
dserror=0 rxerror=0 trunc=0 vlen=0 iface=1 rlen=96 lctr=0 wlen=68
pad=0x00 offset=0x00
dst=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff src=ca:fe:ba:be:ca:fe
etype=0x0800
45 00 00 32 00 00 40 00 40 11 50 ff c0 a8 34 35         E..2..@.@.P...45
c0 a8 34 36 80 01 00 00 00 1e 00 00 08 08 08 08         ..46............
08 08 50 e6 61 c3 85 21 01 00 de ad be ef 85 d7         ..P.a..!........
91 21 6f 9a 32 94 fd 07 01 00 de ad be ef 85 d7         .!o.2...........


print 2: file offset 0x60
ts=0x584819041ff52b00 2016-12-07 14:13:24.124834716 UTC
type: ERF Ethernet
dserror=0 rxerror=0 trunc=0 vlen=0 iface=1 rlen=96 lctr=0 wlen=68
pad=0x00 offset=0x00
dst=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff src=ca:fe:ba:be:ca:fe
etype=0x0800
45 00 00 32 00 00 40 00 40 11 50 ff c0 a8 34 35         E..2..@.@.P...45
c0 a8 34 36 80 01 00 00 00 1e 00 00 08 08 08 08         ..46............
08 08 68 e7 61 c3 85 21 01 00 de ad be ef 86 d7         ..h.a..!........
91 21 c5 34 77 bd fd 07 01 00 de ad be ef 86 d7         .!.4w...........
```

**Expected output**

I just want to replace the dots and colons in the time field (before UTC) and get the entire value.

```
141324124834649,85d79121
141324124834716,86d79121
```

**What I have done so far**
I have extracted the fields after "." but not sure how to replace the colons and get the entire time value.

```
awk -F '[= ]' '$NF == "UTC"{split($4,b,".");s=b[2]",";a=15} /de ad be ef/{s=s $a $(a+1);if(a==1)print s;a=1}' data.log

124834649,85d79121
124834716,86d79121
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '$NF == "UTC"{gsub("[.:]","",$3);s=$3",";a=15} /de ad be ef/{s=s $a $(a+1);if(a==1)print s;a=1}' data.log
```

Result:

```
141324124834649,85d79121
141324124834716,86d79121
```

PS: it can be simplified with `getline` :

```
awk '$NF == "UTC"{gsub("[.:]","",$3);s=$3","} /de ad be ef/{s=s $15 $16;getline;print(s $1 $2)}' data.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the time part like this:

```
$ awk '/UTC/ {split($0,a); gsub(/[\.:]/,"",a[3]); print a[3]}' file
141324124834649
141324124834716
```

Answer (score 1):

for the UTC part, (rest of the code is the same

```
awk '/UTC$/{gsub(/[\.:]/,"");print $3}' YourFile
```

- just remove the ":" and "." and take the field value, other part of the line don't have those 2 character, so is not modified
- $NF test is replaced by /UTC$/, a bit faster and simpler (OMHO)

the full code

```
awk -F '[= ]' '/UTC$/{gsub(/[\.:]/,"");s=$3",";a=15} /de ad be ef/{s=s $a $(a+1);if(a==1)print s;a=1}' YourFile
```